# Using Strings as Variable/Object Names in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am dealing with fractals.  You start with a rectangle, and that shape is decreased by a given decay rate. I have it set up to do the first 10 iterations of the given scenario, and each scenario looks like this:

```
y_1 = dec_y(y_1)
y_2 = dec_y(y_2)
a_y = [y_1, y_2]
rect_1 = TkcRectangle.new(canvas, [0,0], a_y)
```

where `dec_y` is defined as the following:

```
def dec_y(y)
    to_ret = y / $rate
    return to_ret
end
```

I want to turn the first snippet into a function/method (not exactly sure what the Ruby term is...), so that each iteration will just be a single line referencing a method, which makes the problem more extensible.  But, I need each `TkcRectangle` to have a different name.  The way I want to set it up, each `TkcRectangle` will have the same name.  But, if I can set the name of the object to a string passed as an argument, then I should not have a problem.

How do I define the name of an object with a given string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit : Code has not been tested, but will give you the idea.*

Instead of naming each element, you can use an array and use the index instead

```
rectangles_array = Array.new
for each loop
  rectangles_array << create_rectangle_object(y_1, y_2, canvas)
end for each loop

def dec_y(y)
  to_ret = y / $rate
  return to_ret
end

def create_rectangle_object(y_1, y_2, canvas)
  return TkcRectangle.new(canvas, [0,0], [dec_y(y_1), dec_y(y_2)])
end
```

If you really want to name it read about structs.. Something like

```
MyRectangleStruct = Struct.new(:obj_name, :x1, :y1, :x2, :y2)
puts MyRectangleStruct.new(:obj_name => 'First_rec', .....)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly the for loop is doing?

Comment: As you start to solve the next problem, I doubt that you will need to name your objects.  The index should be sufficient.  Sorry, if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, I think I get it...  I should be able to get this to work, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
define_method(method_name, &block)
```

with `method_name` being any string and `&block` being a block of ruby code; usually it looks something like this:

```
define_method(method_name) do
  your code goes here
end
```